# matching multiple line in python regular expression

Tags: python

I want to extract the data between `<tr>` tags from an html page. I used the following code.But i didn't get any result. The html between the `<tr>` tags is in multiple lines

```
category =re.findall('<tr>(.*?)</tr>',data);
```

Please suggest a fix for this problem.

Comment: read the docs: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.S

Comment: Or one paragraph above: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE :)

Comment: @Tomasz: but **do read** beyond the header ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

just to clear up the issue. Despite all those links to `re.M` it wouldn't work here as simple skimming of the its explanation would reveal. You'd need `re.S`, if you wouldn't try to parse html, of course:

```
>>> doc = """<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>"""

>>> re.findall('<tr>(.*?)</tr>', doc, re.S)
['\n        <td>row 1, cell 1</td>\n        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>\n    ', 
 '\n        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>\n        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>\n    ']
>>> re.findall('<tr>(.*?)</tr>', doc, re.M)
[]
```

Comment: `re.findall('<tr>(.*?)</tr>', doc, re.S)` can also be written as `re.findall('(?s)<tr>(.*?)</tr>', doc)`.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use regex, use a HTML parser such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
html = '<html><body>foo<tr>bar</tr>baz<tr>qux</tr></body></html>'

import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.findAll("tr")
```

Result:

```
[<tr>bar</tr>, <tr>qux</tr>]
```

If you just want the contents, without the tr tags:

```
for tr in soup.findAll("tr"):
    print tr.contents
```

Result:

```
bar
qux
```

Using an HTML parser isn't as scary as it sounds! And it will work more reliably than any regex that will be posted here.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use regular expressions to parse HTML. Use an HTML parser such as [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 2):

```
pat=re.compile('<tr>(.*?)</tr>',re.DOTALL|re.M)
print pat.findall(data)
```

Or non regex way,

```
for item in data.split("</tr>"):
    if "<tr>" in item:
       print item[item.find("<tr>")+len("<tr>"):]
```

Answer (score 0):

As other have suggested the specific problem you are having can be resolved by **allowing multi-line matching using [`re.MULTILINE`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE)**

However **you are going down a treacherous patch parsing [HTML with regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)**. Use an XML/HTML parser instead, [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html) works great for this!

```
doc = """<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>"""

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)
all_trs = soup.findAll("tr")
```